# Protecting of witness folder in Exchange 2010 DAG

Tags: exchange

I have some recovery software and Exchange DAG cluster under protection of it. Should i also add a witness server under protection? Or i can just recreate a witness folder using Exchange Management Shell if it will be lost and everything will be ok?

Answer (score 2):

You can always assign a new witness server for the DAG if necessary, so it's not critical.

```
Set-DatabaseAvailabilityGroup -Name MyDAGName -WitnessServer SRV01 -WitnessDirectory C:\DAGWitness
```